# Synchronize Infinispan cache entries with database

Tags: jpa-2.0, jboss6.x, infinispan

I want to  know whether I can use Infinispan for cached data synchronization with Oracle database. This is my scenario. I have two main applications. One is highly concurrent use app and the second is used as admin module. Since it is highly concurrent I want to reduce database connections (Load the entities into cache (read write enable) and use it from this place without calling database). But meantime I want to update database according to the cache changes because admin module is using database directly. Can that update process (cache to  database) handle in entity level without involving application? Please let me know whether Infinispan supports this scenario or not. If supports please share ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Infinispan supports this use case.

This should be simple configuration "problem" only. All you need to use is properly configured CacheStore with `passivation disabled`. It will keep your cache (used by highly concurrent application) synchronized with database.

What does it exactly cause?

> When passivation is disabled, whenever an element is modified, added
>   or removed, then that modification is persisted in the backend store
>   via the cache loader. There is no direct relationship between eviction
>   and cache loading. If you don't use eviction, what's in the persistent
>   store is basically a copy of what's in memory.

By memory is meant a cache here.
If you want to know even more about this and about other interesting options please see: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Cache+Loaders+and+Stores#CacheLoadersandStores-cachepassivation

Maybe it's worth to consider aforementioned eviction. Whether to disable or enable it. It depends mainly on load generated by your highly concurrent application.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this only works when you use Infinispan in the same cluster for the admin module. If you load A in memory with Infinispan, change A to something else in the database directly with the admin module, then Infinispan will not know A has been updated.